# Getting next and previous MySQL id according to views

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database that im saving post id, post and views. I want to add a link to next and previous post based on views.

```
-------------------------------
| Id  | Post       | views    |
-------------------------------
| 1   | Title 01   |   10     |
| 2   | Title 02   |   20     |
| 3   | Title 03   |     5    |
| 4   | Title 04   |     0    |
| 5   | Title 05   |     0    |
| 6   | Title 06   |     0    |
| 7   | Title 06   |     6    |
-------------------------------
```

So I try following queries. `$post_id` is the current post id.

```
// Previous 
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id>'$post_id' ORDER BY views ASC LIMIT 1 

// Next
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id<'$post_id' ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 1
```

Above queries are returning wrong results.

```
// Previous 
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE views>'$views' ORDER BY views ASC LIMIT 1 

// Next
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE views<'$views' ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 1
```

Those are returning results until the zero occurs (from example data I added above) so I change where clause to `views>='$views'` (previous) and `views<='$views'`(next) this it returns wrong results.

I know this seems like a simple question but I search everywhere couldn’t find anything normally it’s easy to get next and previous posts according to post id but views it doesn’t work at all.

Your time and answers are highly appreciated.

**Edit:** views column is in `INT`

Bit more details.

My parent page winch call views have below query

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE views DESC LIMIT 10
```

So this will out put post id's `2,1,7,3,4,5,6` when user click any of these posts it will go the post that display full post with next and previous navigation so i want the previous and next navigation to be the same order as parent page which is `2,1,7,3,4,5,6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep navigation less random, you can add sort by other field. For example, by Id. You need exact algorithm in order to get same results every time. This is just example of such algorithm:

1. Sort posts by views count in descending order.
2. If two posts has equal views, than sort these posts by Id in ascending order.

In this case we can always select single, not random, next (previous) post.

```sql
-- Previous post
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE (views > '$views') OR (views = '$views' AND Id < '$post_id')
ORDER BY views ASC, Id DESC
LIMIT 1;

-- Next post
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE (views < '$views') OR (views = '$views' AND Id > '$post_id')
ORDER BY views DESC, Id ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Also, you need to modify query on your parent page and add sort here too:

```sql
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY views DESC, Id ASC LIMIT 10
```

**Note:**

Site can be used with multiple users at once. And such navigation will not work in general case. For example, user1 opened first post, then go to next (second) post. At this moment user2 opened first post too and **it's views count was changed**. If user1 goes to previous page (first) now, link to 'next' on it may not point to second page.

Comment: so i just have to filter which is more then zero am i correct?

Comment: Add more details in your question then. For example, for post with id=5 what posts are you expecting as next/previous? My queries will find id=3 as previous post and 4 or 6 as next post. I understand your algorithm this way. Is it wrong?

Comment: i added bit more details. issue its its seems to show the same post again when there is multiple posts with same view value ex: if it shows page 2 and then 5 with same views it will go back again to page 2. to be more clear 2, 5, 2, 5 like stuck in a loop.

Comment: OK, it's more clear now. You want less random in navigation, right? If next page has same views count and we go to it, then link to previous page on it must be exact to our previous visited page, not to any page with same views count.

Comment: I corrected answer, so now it must fill your requirements. Check, please. But note, that such kind of navigation can be easily broken by multiple users at once.

Comment: work perfectly but may i know what you mean by can be broken easily?

Answer (score 0):

To get previous value.Here find all which have views less than current and then sort in desc order and last one is then the previous one.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE views<'$views' ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 1
```

To get next value .Here find all which have views greater than current and then sort in asc order and first one is then the next one.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE views>'$views' ORDER BY views ASC LIMIT 1
```

Here only edge case will be when views are equal,in that case you have to get all views which are equal and then order by id also and then if views are equal add one more condition id > current id and vice versa for previous one.

Comment: Sorry i did the DESC order. mistakenly i added both as ASC. However if there is more then one result with the same view amount iit want get the previous or next.

Comment: @max i have already told how to handle that case in my answer.